# APACHE ON CENTOS 7 - Error while trying to access web page by using url domain name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, apache-httpd

I installed Apache web server (httpd) on CentOS 7 server, virtual machine, created using Vagrant on Ubuntu 20.04 GUI. On CentOS server, I specifically configured certain files for Apache server to work. I tested it with IP on Ubuntu browser and it worked like a charm. Once again, in this case, CentOS server is just a virtual machine that I created on Ubuntu GUI, and Ubuntu is the only place where I can test if apache works on a browser.

Afterwards I wanted to configure apache so that it uses domain name url alongside IP. Here are the steps I followed:

Setting up virtual host:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/html


chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/html


chmod -R 755 /var/www/example.com/html/index.html


nano /var/www/example.com/html/index.html
```

In index.html I just wrote some random text to display.

After that, I created folders `/etc/httpd/sites-available` and `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled`, and also the config file `example.com.conf` and filled the config file with this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I just added `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` at the end of the text to tell Apache to look for virtual hosts in `sites-enabled` folder.

Then I just restarted httpd as so `sudo systemctl restart httpd`.

Also to mention, in this scenario I am using `example.com` just for demonstration, but I did change that to my own random domain name.

Now comes the big part, on Ubuntu I opened the browser, typed in the domain name that I created, and it outputs

> Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

So after little bit of researching, I figured that I might have to define CentOS server's IP alongside the domain name in `/etc/hosts` in Ubuntu. And that is what I did. Then again I tried to execute domain name on the browser and then it outputs this:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>
> Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

So just to clarify, on Ubuntu I can open CentOS apache server by using its IP, but not the domain name.

Any suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Comment: Use curl to access the web site. Check the Apache log files.

Comment: Did curl, doesn't work. Configured apache log multiple times, still nothing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "configured Apache log files". You need to **read** them and find log messages that relate to the problem.